# Import Plugin on localhost Craft 2 crashes

Tags: plugins, craft2, import

I'm using the import plugin by Bob Oldehampsink on a localhost Craft2 site, but, although it appears to have installed successfully, when I attempt to upload the .csv file and click on 'next,' I'm met with a blank screen.
I've checked the format of the .csv and have made various changes, but I still get the blank screen (I only ever see the first screen in the Import plugin).
Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a PHP memory limit issue but it's hard to say until you get access to the log files or can output the error to the browser instead of a blank page.

I would first make sure `devMode` is enabled in Craft. Then I would look at the log files in `storage/logs/web.log` or `storage/logs/php-errors.log`. There might be a lot of stuff logged already, so sometimes it's easier to delete everything in `logs` and then redo the import and see what errors were logged.